# Deploy with capistrano to different server directories at the same time

Tags: deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to modify my capistrano file to deploy into 2 different servers at the same time (don't really want to cap production1 deploy and cap production2 deploy and cap forever deploy) and there's one restriction that I don't know how to solve: the application must be deployed in different directories (let's say in /foo in server A and in the other in /bar in server B)

I tried to play with the deploy_to variable but with no luck, because looks to be a global one for all servers.

Anybody knows if there's a way to set it up per server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make both servers look the same with a symlink.